# Optimize Mysql & My.cnf to 32g Ram & 8 Core CPU?

Tags: mysql

please , what is the best configuration to Innodb because mysql eat CPU on linux server this is my configuration but I don`t sure it matches best solution

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size =24G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
join_buffer_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
thread_cache_size = 32
#max_allowed_packet = 1600M
max_allowed_packet = 100M
tmp_table_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=3G
```

Answer (score 1):

No to these:

```
join_buffer_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
#max_allowed_packet = 1600M
tmp_table_size = 1G
```

Don't set any of them to more than 1% of RAM.  Otherwise, you threaten to consume so much RAM as to cause swapping.  Swapping hurts performance *a lot*.  Anyway, big values for those are mostly in the realm of "diminishing returns".

The most important setting is fine as you have it:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 24G
```

You will probably never use all 8 cores unless you have some really inefficient queries.  And they can probably be fixed with a better `INDEX` or query reformulation.